# Java TreeSet with additional condition

Tags: java, data-structures

In Java I use a TreeSet to store some data points with a timestamp. Let's say a data point, let's call it `RestaurantExperience`, looks like this:

```
{
  timestamp: <long>,
  restaurant: <string>,
  tasty: <boolean>
}
```

Now I can use the TreeSet's `ceiling` and `floor` methods to find the restaurant where I had any experience at a given time. However, I'm interested in the restaurant where I had a 'tasty' experience at a given time.

That means I'm trying to find a data point *near* a timestamp **and** with a specific value for `tasty` at the same time. How would I go about doing that?

Ideally I would add an extra condition to my `floor` and `ceiling` methods, but I don't know how. Otherwise, is there a data structure better suited for this?

Comment: any reason to do timestamp: <double> and not a long?

Comment: Do you want to have both of these constraints at the same time or use them separately?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ In the `TreeSet` class.

Comment: I've updated my question!

Comment: There's no reason to use `floor` and `ceiling` with a `boolean`.  You can just filter the `Set` to find every restaurant that was tasty with a `Stream`.

Comment: I'm trying to find a data point near a timestamp *and* with a specific value for tasty at the same time ;)

Answer (score 1):

Write a Comparator that first compares the boolean tasty, then compares the long timestamp

```
int compareTo(RestaurantExperience r1, RestaurantExperience r2) {
      if(r1.isTasty() == r2.isTasty()){
          return Long.compare(r1.getTimestamp(), r2.getTimestamp())
      else
          return r1.isTasty() ? 1 : -1;
}
```

Then use this when initializing your TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Guava's [Sets.filter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#filter-java.util.NavigableSet-com.google.common.base.Predicate-) to filter the data points I'm interested in. The resulting NavigableSet (which still has `floor` & `ceiling`) can then be used for searching by timestamp.